# Read Message from WebApp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a WebApp Add-on in Google Sheets. Below is the Addon and webapp script. I want to read validation/error message from webapp and display to user.
Like I will send message from doPost(e) like "Check Values" and user should get this as message box.

```
function copyData() {
 var ss_id = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  
  //This is the Web App URL.
  var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/<id>/exec";  

  var payload = {
  "ss_id" : ss_id, // Modified
}

  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "payload" : payload,
    "followRedirects" : true,
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
  };

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);  
  
}
```

> ```
> function doPost(e) {
>
>   var ss_id = e.parameter.ss_id; // Modified
>
> var response = {
>   "status" : "FAILED",
>   "ss_id" : ss_id,
> };
>
>   //var ss_id = ss_id[0];
>   
>    //Use your spreadsheetID to get Output Sheet
>   var Manager_SS=SpreadsheetApp.openById('<id>');
>   var Manager_Sheet=Manager_SS.getSheetByName('Consolidated_Data');
>     
>   var FrontDesk_ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss_id);
>   var FrontDesk_sheet = FrontDesk_ss.getSheetByName('Data');
>   
>   //Get front desk data
>   
>   var sData = FrontDesk_sheet.getRange("A2:C10").getValues();
>
>   //Copy data from Front Desk to Manager Sheet. 
>   Manager_Sheet.getRange("A2:C10").clear();
>   Manager_Sheet.getRange("A2:C10").setValues(sData);
>
>   //Update done after copying data.
>   FrontDesk_sheet.getRange('D1:D10').setValue('Done');
>   
>   var response = {
>     "status" : "SUCCESS",
>     "sData" : sData,
>   };     
>
>   return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response));
>
> }
> ```

Comment: So, your goal is the following. The user clicks somewhere in the Google Sheets interfaces, this sends a message to your web application containing information from the sheets, the web application performs some kind of validation and returns information to the user, based on the content of this validation, the user see one message or another, right?

Comment: Yes, copyData is Add On users can access from Extensions. They click on it to send data to manager sheet through doPost(e). In doPost(e) I should validate and send a message back to user. User do not have access to manager sheet, so I am using webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this example I am using a [bounded script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound), but this should be the same for an [Editor Add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/types#editor_add-ons)

In the spreadsheet we want to validate, we create a custom menu to call a function that makes a POST request to our Web App. Depending on the response, we display one content or another.

```js
const UI = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
const onOpen = () => {
  /* Adds the custom menu */
  UI.createMenu('Custom Function').addItem('Is Valid?', 'checkValidity').addToUi()
}
const checkValidity = () => {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch
    (
      /* Change it for your URL */
      "https://script.google.com/macros/s/<ID>/exec",
      {
        "method": "post",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        /* In this example I only send the ID of the Spreadsheet */
        "payload": JSON.stringify(
          {
            "ss_id": SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()
          }
        )
      }
    )
  /* Depending on the response from the Web App */
  /* We show different messages */
  const { MSG } = JSON.parse(res.getContentText())
  UI.alert(MSG === "OK" ? "IS VALID" : "IS NOT VALID")
}
```

After we create a Web App that validates the ID. In this example I am only validating that the ID is contained in an array of valid IDs, but this should be replaced by whatever you need. As a response I only send a simple "OK" or "NOT OK", but this can be replaced with any kind of data.

```js
const doPost = (e) => {
  /* We perform the checks we need */
  /* In this example only checking if the id is contained in an array */
  /* This should be changed to perform the desired checks */
  const validID = ["<VALID_ID_1>","<VALID_ID_2>"]
  const { ss_id } = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)
  /* SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss_id).copy("my_new_copy") */
  const checker = validID.includes(ss_id)
  /* We send back the response */
  /* Depending on the checker value */
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(
    {
      "MSG": checker ? "OK" : "NOT OK"
    }
  )).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
}
```

Comment: Thank You. I just need to know how to send and read data. I can use the MSG example. Thanks for the detailed code.

Answer (score 1):

#### Reading Validation Error from Webapp

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="txt1" name="id" placeholder="Enter Numbers only"/>
      <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="processForm(this.parentNode);" />
    </form>
    <script>
      function processForm(obj) {
        console.log(obj.id.value);
        if(obj.id.value.match(/[A-Za-z]/)) {
          google.script.run.displayError("Invalid Characters Found in id field");
        } else {
          google.script.run.sendData(obj);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

GS:

```
function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log(e.postData.contents);
  Logger.log(e.postData.type);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  let row = [];
  Object.keys(data).forEach(k => row.push(data[k]));
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(row))
  sh.appendRow(row);
}

function sendData(obj) {
  const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  const params={"contentType":"application/json","payload":JSON.stringify(obj),"muteHttpExceptions":true,"method":"post","headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer " +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);
}

function displayError(msg) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(msg);
}

function launchMyDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah1'),'My Dialog');
}
```